# User input geographic point syntax validation

Tags: java, gis, geo, geotools

I'm trying to work with geographic points in a java project.
I started to look into good practice, started looking into GeoTols which seems to be the reference for java.

What I'm trying to do is validate a user input for geographic points.
The user input is JSON file. So I'm parsing the file, and I would like to find something that validates the syntax and that a point at this coordinates is likely.

I couldn't find it (maybe I searched wrong) in GeoTools.
Thanks!

Comment: What are your criteria for determining if a point is "likely" at a given set of coordinates?

Comment: There is a GeoJSON datastore in GeoTools

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for your answers.
I may have used the wrong word. My need is to assert that a geograpohic point exists.
I'm not at the stage where i try to get en address from it.
But i would like to get en error if i get something like 100.10, 200.30 (witch wouldn't exist).
And i didn't find that in GeoTools. I figured there would be a methode like `isValideCoordinate(lat, lon)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

validation coordinates should be determined from the reference coordinate system. you can visit [epsg.io](https://epsg.io/4326) like wgs84 bounds, use the following code to determine whether the coordinates are within the corresponding interval.

```java
package org.example;


import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;
import org.opengis.referencing.cs.CoordinateSystem;
import org.opengis.referencing.cs.CoordinateSystemAxis;

/**
 * @author Arjen10
 * @date 2023/9/15 下午4:55
 */
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CoordinateReferenceSystem decode = CRS.decode("EPSG:4326", true);
        CoordinateSystem coordinateSystem = decode.getCoordinateSystem();
        CoordinateSystemAxis axis = coordinateSystem.getAxis(0);
        CoordinateSystemAxis axis1 = coordinateSystem.getAxis(1);
        double maxX = axis.getMaximumValue();
        double maxY = axis1.getMaximumValue();
        double minX = axis.getMinimumValue();
        double minY = axis1.getMinimumValue();
        System.out.println("wgs84 maxX " + maxX);
        System.out.println("wgs84 maxY " + maxY);
        System.out.println("wgs84 minX " + minX);
        System.out.println("wgs84 minY " + minY);

        double userInputX = 180d;
        double userInputY = 90.1;

        if (userInputX > maxX || userInputX < minX) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("error x");
        }

        if (userInputY > maxY || userInputY < minY) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("error y");
        }
    }

}
```